# Decode byte to utf-8 in Python: 'errors="ignore"' not working

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

**Code:**

```
def reqURL():
    request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat')
    html = request.read()
    html = html.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
    print(html)
```

**Error:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u017d' in position 468663: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Question:**
I read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) and put `errors="ignore"` in my code but it isn't working! Why?

Comment: You have an *Encode* error, caused by trying to print Unicode text to a Windows console that can't handle your text.

Comment: This is why the traceback is important; look at that too, not just the exception you get. The traceback would have shown you that the error takes place on the `print(html)` line, not the line with the `html.decode()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartijnPieters . I find a solution on this Post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how) - Just type "chcp 65001" in the windows console and it is working.

Comment: Take into account that your console font still may cause issues too. Not all fonts can handle the wide array of text Unicode can encode.